# Getting Invariant violation: ListView in react native, but i haven't used any listviews

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I get Invariant violation: ListView in react native. I have searched across the files of my project and I have realized that I haven't used any listviews. But why I get this error? I know I can replace ListView and can fix the error. But what can I do if there are no ListViews?

Are there any other packages which use this ListView package? What may be the reason for this?

Comment: kindly check packages which you have used which contain depreciated ListView and remove that package which are not maintained well

Comment: I'll take a look